# Wordpress redirecting to localhost instead of virtual host when being proxied by Webpack Dev Server

Tags: apache, proxy, virtualhost, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to do a relatively simple set up with:

- An Apache server with a virtual host for the HTML.
- Webpack and the Webpack Dev Server for asset reloading and generation.

To accomplish this, the [`Webpack Dev Server proxies`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy) the other server to pass through requests that it doesn't know how to handle.

Using a basic python server (which works):

1. Start the python webserver on http://localhost:5000.
2. Run npm start.
3. Webpack Dev Server starts and proxies the python server using http://localhost:9090.
4. Visit http://localhost:9090 and see HTML result of python server plus Webpack assets.

Using Apache server:

1. Start the Apache server.
2. Run npm start.
3. Webpack dev server starts and proxies the Apache server using http://localhost:9090.
4. Visit localhost:9090 the browser automatically redirects to http://localhost and displays "It works!".

If I separately visit http://vhost.name in the browser I see the correct HTML. My environment is the default Apache Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) on Mac OSX El Capitan.

**package.json**

```js
"scripts": {
  "test": "node server.js",
  "start": "npm run start-dev-server",
  "start-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server 'webpack-dev-server/client?/' --host 0.0.0.0 --port 9090 --progress --colors",
  "build": "webpack"
},
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
/*global require module __dirname*/
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: [
            'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9090',
            'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
            './src/app.js'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: '[name]_bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:9090/dist'
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        proxy: {
            // Python server: works as expected at localhost:9090
            // '*': 'http://localhost:5000'

            // Apache virtual host: redirects to localhost instead of
            // serving localhost:9090
            '*': 'http://vhost.name'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
};
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```xml
<VirtualHost vhost.name:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Path/To/vhost.name"
    ServerName vhost.name
        <Directory "/Path/To/vhost.name">
            Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            # OSX 10.10 / Apache 2.4
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost

127.0.0.1   vhost.name
```

Comment: I have browser-sync installed on my computer, and if I run browser-sync start --proxy http://vhost.name and visit http://localhost:3000 then it works fine. Tearing my hair out...

Comment: Watching the network traffic in either Chrome tools or Charles traffic proxy, http://vhost.name:9090 is doing a 301 Moved Permanently, which the browser then interprets to try localhost without the port. According to this comment (http://serverfault.com/a/361324) "Look for two things in your Apache config; Redirect, and RewriteRule directives that have an R flag. If those aren't in place, then Apache isn't doing the redirect". The virtual host is actually pointing to a Wordpress site with the following standard rewrite rules:

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Still looking, but isolated the issue (I think). I have a basic PHP page on a separate Apache VHost which works as expected. In the above example I am serving from Wordpress so it looks like this is removing the port.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wordpress uses [canonical URLs to help normalize URLs](https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2007/09/25/wordpress-23-canonical-urls/) for content from different sources:

> [Y]ou can’t control who links to you, and third parties can make errors when typing or copy-pasting your URLs. This canonical URL degeneration has a way of propogating. That is, Site A links to your site using a non-canonical URL. Then Site B see’s Site A’s link, and copy-pastes it into their blog. If you allow a non-canonical URL to stay in the address bar, people will use it. That usage is detrimental to your search engine ranking, and damages the web of links that makes up the Web. By redirecting to the canonical URL, we can help stop these errors from propagating, and at least generate 301 redirects for the errors that people may make when linking to your blog.

This rewriting is what strips the Webpack-dev-server port number when attempting to proxy. The solution is to add in your theme/functions.php:

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

We obviously don't want this running on the live site, so add a variable to the wp_config.php to set depending on environment:

**wp-config.php**

```
// Toggle to disable canonical URLs to allow port numbers.
// Required for Webpack-dev-server proxying.
define('DISABLE_CANONICAL', 'Y', true);
```

**yourtheme/functions.php**

```
// Hack for Webpack dev server
if (DISABLE_CANONICAL == 'Y') {
    remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
}
```

I have experienced issues with the browser "caching" the previous URL redirect, so when you make a change it may not appear immediately. Try opening the URL in incognito mode, using a different browser, or restarting the Webpack and Apache servers.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, but with Nginx. Disabling canonical redirects didn't do the trick for me. Was there anything else you did to get this working?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Nginx and any differences between it and Apache's handling of canonical redirects. That said the Apache investigation I did was a red herring for the problem I had - which was the Wordpress code doing URL redirects based on canonical URLs. In telling Wordpress not to do this fixed my issue. Maybe URL handling in Wordpress when installed on Nginx behaves differently to when it is installed on Apache (seems unlikely), otherwise you could be having a different problem altogether. Maybe the Nginx equivalent of mod_rewrite?

Comment: Could be. I did check the configuration files and didn't find anything that points to this issue. SSL / https is a potential issue too, but since it works with Browsersync just fine...

Comment: Basically WordPress was stripping anything passed the URL (port/trailing slash). Browsersync always did work just fine, but the intricacies of Webpack's IP settings means you have to nail it. Some auto rewrite will be occurring that will be messing it up.

Comment: One more thing: did you do *any* tricks to `siteurl` or `home`? I'm fairly certain now that my issues are caused by WordPress siteurl _not_ containing the port number I'm using on webpack-dev-server, and I also think that I figured a way to manually override those in wp-config, just for webpack-dev-server, but I can't test it in a while.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I wasn't doing anything more fancy within Wordpress, URL was set via vhost and ports were only within webpack.