# WordPress redirecting to siteurl when accessed via webpack-dev-server proxy

Tags: wordpress, redirect, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

This question has historical value, so I'm updating it a bit. It's the top result for "webpack-dev-server wordpress redirect" in Google. While the accepted solution worked for Webpack 2, it might not work anymore. If it doesn't you can refer to my [wordpress-theme-base repository](https://github.com/k1sul1/wordpress-theme-base), which is built using Webpack 4.

---

First of all, this is related to [Wordpress redirecting to localhost instead of virtual host when being proxied by Webpack Dev Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432990/wordpress-redirecting-to-localhost-instead-of-virtual-host-when-being-proxied-by). I'm facing a similar problem, but the only solution didn't really do anything for me.

I'm running WordPress 4.7 inside a Vagrant development machine, and it responds to http://wordpress.local just like it should. Previously I've used Browsersync to watch my files and trigger a refresh, and this works as expected: `browser-sync start --proxy 'https://wordpress.local' --files '**/dist/js/*.js, **/*.css, **/*.php'`.

However, with webpack-dev-server I'm unable to replicate the behaviour. This is what should happen.

1. Server starts in `https://localhost:9000`
2. Navigating to `https://localhost:9000` should present me with the same page as navigating to `https://wordpress.local`, without any redirections. Site works as it was `https://wordpress.local`, but the URL is `https://localhost:9000`.
3. Changes happen, page gets reloaded.

Instead, this happens.

- Navigating to `https://localhost:9000` *redirects* me to `https://wordpress.local` with a 301. I've disabled canonical redirects with `remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');` but doesn't help.
- Navigating to `https://localhost:9000/404` presents me a 404 page that is provided by my theme. No redirect happens.
- Navigating to `https://localhost:9000/existing-page/` *redirects* me to `https://localhost/existing-page/` with a 301.

What on earth is going on? I've narrowed the problem to WordPress, as proxying a non-WordPress directory works as expected:

Direct, contents of $_SERVER: https://gist.github.com/k1sul1/0aff7ba905464ca7852f2ce00b459922

Proxied, contents of $_SERVER: https://gist.github.com/k1sul1/f090aa103dc3a3cb0b339269560ac19d

I've tried playing around with headers and such, without luck. Here's what my webpack.config.js looks like:

```
const path = require('path');
const url = 'https://wordpress.local/';
const themeDir = '/wp-content/themes/themename/';

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: url
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
    https: url.indexOf('https') > -1 ? true : false,
    publicPath: themeDir,
    proxy: {
      '*': {
        'target': url,
        'secure': false
      },
      // '/': { // This doesn't do much. 
        // target: url,
        // secure: false
      // }
    },
  }
};
```

**TL;DR:** How do I replicate Browsersync behaviour with webpack-dev-server without WordPress going crazy?

Comment: Thanks for the above link to your WP theme, with the updated fixes that worked for me! What's weird is I didn't have any issues with _redirection_. If I went to my proxied URL, it just went there. My issue was all the links on the site (i.e. navigation) were lacking the port number. However, your "headers" fix to allow access to WDS data from anywhere of course then solved my issues since I have no port numbers! Would be curious to know why I didn't have a redirection issue though...

Comment: Yeah, the links are unchanged when using the proxied version. Previously, I used a little JS `if (module.hot) { fixLinks() }` to mitigate the problem, but I've stopped using it in favour of going to the WordPress site directly. @Trevor

Comment: It hasn't always been issue free, sometimes when I started a new project, the hot reload wouldn't work etc, but I guess those issues were caused by bugs in dependencies. Right now I'm working on a React application that's embedded into WordPress. Here's the config: https://gist.github.com/k1sul1/0d8d9e83037fa2ed9c1a974e93035c25

In this case, I use localhost:8080 as my dev URL, which proxies to WordPress. This way I can enqueue the assets with WordPress mechanisms and take full advantage of webpack-dev-server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did eventually solve this. The magic lines that go into the proxy config are `changeOrigin: true` and `autoRewrite: true`. Those options go into [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware).

Any changes to WordPress domain or config are unnecessary.

```
const path = require('path');
const pjson = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'package.json'));

const isWin = /^win/.test(process.platform);
const isMac = /^darwin/.test(process.platform);
const isHTTPS = pjson.wptheme.proxyURL.includes('https');

exports.devServer = ({ host, port } = {}) => {
  const options = {
    host: host || process.env.HOST || 'localhost', 
    port: port || process.env.PORT || 8080,
  };
  options.publicPath = (isHTTPS ? 'https' : 'http') + '://' + options.host + ':' + options.port + pjson.wptheme.publicPath;

  return {
    devServer: {
      watchOptions: {
        poll: isWin || isMac ? undefined : 1000,
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
      },

      https: isHTTPS,
      stats: 'errors-only',
      host: options.host,
      port: options.port,
      overlay: {
        errors: true,
        warnings: false,
      },

      open: true,
      hotOnly: true,

      proxy: {
        '/': {
          target: pjson.wptheme.proxyURL,
          secure: false,
          changeOrigin: true,
          autoRewrite: true,
          headers: {
            'X-ProxiedBy-Webpack': true,
          },
        },
      },

      publicPath: options.publicPath,
    },
  };
};
```

The values referenced from package.json look like this:

```
"wptheme": {
  "publicPath": "/wp-content/themes/themefolder/dist/",
  "proxyURL": "https://wordpress.local"
},
```

Comment: How do you change your links and assets in your theme to automatically use `localhost:8080` during development? When I use `define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost:8080');` Wordpress redirects like in your initial question, even with using `changeOrigin: true` and `autoRewrite: true`.

Comment: Don't set WP_HOME. I used the custom header that I set to not include a stylesheet when requested via webpack because it doesn't exist (loaded with JS), most likely your target is wrong. Look at changeOrigin here: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#http-proxy-options

Answer (score 2):

It's probably the redirect settings of your Wordpress site. If you access your site through http://localhost:9000 then that should be the domain Wordpress is aware of.

Set it in Wordpress' admin or directly in the database:

```
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = "http://localhost:9000" WHERE `option_name` = "siteurl" OR `option_name` = "home";
```

Comment: But by doing that, I lose the ability to access the installation unproxied, which can cause problems. I've almost full parity between dev and prod instances, and that would hurt that parity quite a bit ;) I think Browsersync serves more as a man-in-the-middle server that send my request to WordPress unmodified, and rewrites the response so everything keeps working. I think I need webpack-dev-server to do that, or similar.

Comment: Currently I'm just using Browsersync and running Webpack through it, but I'd rather run it through dev-server because it's faster.

Comment: Apparently I can change `siteurl` and `home` with wp-config without actually touching the database using `define()`. I just need to somehow communicate the fact that I'm using webpack-dev-server to WordPress and apply a tad different configuration. Headers in devServer settings could work. Have an upvote.