# Is there a way to achieve that Webpack Dev server proxy to wordpress properly?

Tags: wordpress, webpack, webpack-dev-server, rollup, browser-sync

I've seen some posts about it but with Webpack 5 maybe it can be done without the old problems.
Necessity is basic; use webpack Dev server and HMR for WordPress development. Instead of reloading with browsersync.

Actually there is a post that guy named Christian wasted real time on this in the past. But I can't comment on that answer cuz I don't have the enough rep to comment...

[WordPress redirecting to siteurl when accessed via webpack-dev-server proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43387450/wordpress-redirecting-to-siteurl-when-accessed-via-webpack-dev-server-proxy)

Is there a way or is it worth to invest time on Dev server instead of browsersync?
Any other solutions also accepted. Like if rollup or parcel has a similar option or snowpack maybe.

Comment: Link to "post by Christian" would help.

Comment: I updated for you ;)

Comment: I'm not really in a position to address this, as I don't have the particular stack you are working with, but I do wonder if [webpack encore](https://symfony.com/index.php/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html#installing-encore-in-non-symfony-applications) might offer an alternative to developing and managing assets that would relieve so much reliance on webpack (while still using it).

Answer (score 0):

I will describe how I do it, there are many approaches to this problem, but what I have developed works for me, but it does not mean that it will be useful for you. Unfortunately it is based on browsersync but works on webpack 5 ;)

I'll start with the fact that I have a config folder with webpack.common.js, webpack.dev.js and webpack.prod.js files.

I will only describe the dev version - webpack.dev.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const baseConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

const buildMode =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development';
const { cssLoaders } = require('./util');

// Configure Dev Server
const configureDevServer = () => {
  return {
    writeToDisk: true,
    port: 3000,
  };
};

// Configure Css Loader
const configureCssLoader = () => {
  return {
    test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
    use: ['style-loader', ...cssLoaders],
  };
};

module.exports = merge(baseConfig, {
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'web',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: configureDevServer(),
  module: {
    rules: [configureCssLoader(buildMode)],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(false),
    }),
    new BrowserSyncPlugin(
      {
        watchOptions: {
          aggregateTimeout: 200,
          poll: 1000,
        },
        proxy: 'http://localhost',
        files: [
          './wordpress/wp-content/themes/MY-TEMPLATE/**/*.php',
          './frontend/**/*.js',
          './frontend/**/*.scss',
        ],
      },
      {
        reload: false,
      }
    ),
  ],
});
```

I save files to the disk, in a specific place to my template, `/wordpress/wp-content/themes/MY-TEMPLATE/assets/`
Of course, the whole environment, the base, wordpress stands for a docker.

Each css and js file is saved in the form of `filename: 'js/[name]-[hash].js'` for production version but for dev version `filename: 'js/[name].js'`

Now the most important part is how to download a new file to wordpress every time the file changes, be it css or js.

I have some php functions in function.php

// wordpress/wp-content/themes/MY-TEMPLATE/functions.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */

require get_theme_file_path('/inc/mytemplate_styles_scripts.php');
```

In this file I have a function that downloads the appropriate files depending on whether we are in production or on localhost and puts them in the header if css, and if js then in the footer.

```
/**
 * adding css to head
 */
function kodywig_head_css()
{
  if ($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] !== 'localhost') {
    echo generateLinkOrScript('css', 'share');
  }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'kodywig_head_css', 0);

/**
 * adding js to footer
 */
function kodywig_head_js()
{
  if (is_singular()) {
    echo generateLinkOrScript('js', 'post');
  }
  echo generateLinkOrScript('js', 'share');
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'kodywig_head_js', 0);

/**
 * match file name
 */
function kodywig_matchFile($partOfName, $folder)
{
  $handler = get_template_directory() . '/assets/' . $folder;
  $openHandler = opendir($handler);
  while ($file = readdir($openHandler)) {
    if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {
      if (preg_match("/^" . $partOfName . "(.*)" . $folder . "/i", $file, $name)) {
        return $name[0];
      }
    }
  }
  closedir($openHandler);
}

function generateLinkOrScript($type, $name)
{
  if ($type == 'css') {
    $nameLocal = $name . '-';
  } else {
    $nameLocal = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] != 'localhost' ? $name : $name . '-';
  }

  if ($type == 'css') {
    $html = '<link href="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/' . $type . '/' . kodywig_matchFile($nameLocal, 'css') . '" rel="stylesheet">';
  } else {
    $html = '<script defer src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/' . $type . '/' . kodywig_matchFile($name, 'js') . '"></script>';
  }
  return $html;
}
```

Each js, css change generates new files, which are uploaded to wordpress and the page is automatically reloaded.

If you work on windows, I recommend using wsl2 instead of docker. The compilation and refreshing of the page are extremely fast then.

Here at this link you have practically this solution, it is quite old but already uses webpack5 [docker-wordpress-xdebug](https://github.com/tomik23/docker-wordpress-xdebug)

Comment: First I appreciate your sharing. That is a nice method when it comes to wordpress. Because of using the proper way for wp is enquee things in general. But i need to ask that before test the whole setup, do we have the HMR (https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/) in that setup or is it just another way of reloading(F5, CTRL+R) browser  ?

Comment: I don't use HRM for a simple reason, I needed something that would reload the page also when PHP changed.

Comment: Now i understand you better. We cannot push content into html because `PHP code needs to be run on a server` to output some values. To make it compile our updated php code, we need to make a request to the server via a page reload. So that HMR is not an option for PHP code. It is only for javascript and css. But in this scenario it is useless to implement the HMR for only js and css files. Because if we save a .php file we will lose the state of our app. Thank you again [@grzgorz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10424385/grzegorz-t)